# How to get the jms quickstart packaged with JBoss-Fuse-6.1.0.redhat-355 to work?

Tags: jms, apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

The Karaf output is as under :

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:addurl mvn:org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse/jms/6.1.0.redhat-355/xml/features
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:install quickstart-jms
[Fatal Error] :6:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
Error executing command: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
```

I am not sure where this html element is being used.

`log:display-exception`reveals :

```
2016-02-12 07:36:24,571 | INFO  | l Console Thread | Console | ?
? | 17 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 2.3.0.redhat-610355 | Exception caught while executing command
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".

JBossFuse:karaf@root> log:display-exception
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)[:]
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)[:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeatureValidationUtil.validate(FeatureValidationUtil.java:
52)[23:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.validateRepository(FeaturesServiceImpl
.java:215)[23:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.internalAddRepository(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:256)[23:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.getFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1
015)[23:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.getFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:97
3)[23:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.jav
a:395)[23:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.command.InstallFeatureCommand.doExecute(InstallFeatureCommand.java:
62)[37:org.apache.karaf.features.command:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.command.FeaturesCommandSupport.doExecute(FeaturesCommandSupport.jav
a:41)[37:org.apache.karaf.features.command:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:39)[17:org.
 apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)[17:org.
apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[18:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime:0.11.0.redhat-610355] at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)[18:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime:0.11.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)[18:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime:0.11.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[18:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime:0.11.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[18:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime:0.11.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[18:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime:0.11.0.redhat-610355] at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)[18:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime:0.11.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:189)[17:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-610355]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.DelayedStarted.run(DelayedStarted.java:61)[17:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-610355]

JBossFuse:karaf@root>
```

If anyone can help me get this working it will help.

TIA

Comment: check in your maven repositories the downloaded feature. you are probably behind a proxy which has returned an html page, instead of a feature

Comment: I am doing this from my home office and I dont have any proxies setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got most of the quickstarts (incl the JMS one) to work on this version -> `jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024`. My JDK was `1.7.0_60` and was set to `JAVA_HOME`.